# Error while instantiating selenium chrome driver in Spring MVC Java Controller

Tags: spring, selenium, spring-mvc, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

When I'm running the selenium chrome driver instantiation code in separate java file i'm not getting any error but when trying to run it in controller method of spring mvc then I'm getting following error:

```
Warning:   StandardWrapperValve[dispatcher]: Servlet.service() for servlet dispatcher threw exception
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(ZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable
(DriverService.java:124)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.access$000
(ChromeDriverService.java:32)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable
(ChromeDriverService.java:137)
```

...etc

My spring mvc controller code is as follows:

```
package com.webcrawler;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.List;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import static javax.servlet.SessionTrackingMode.URL;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.openqa.selenium.Alert;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
public class WebCrawlerController {
    @RequestMapping("/index.htm")
   public ModelAndView login(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
            String errorMsg = "";

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\<username>\\Desktop\\chromedriver.exe");
           WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();

          driver.get("https://netforum.acg.org/eweb/DynamicPage.aspx?WebCode=LoginRequired&expires=yes&Site=ACG");


       System.out.println("inside webcrawlerController");
            return new ModelAndView("index");  
    }
```

Am I missing anything ? I'm getting error on the line:

```
WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
```

Comment: Looks like you have a mix of Guava libraries in the classpath.

Comment: @SlavaSemushin And why am I getting an exception ? Can you please help me out ?

Comment: Please, include output of the `mvn dependency:tree` command.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it just deleting a guava library from the pom file